# What is the correct way to update an slqalchemy orm column from a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I've loaded some data and modified one column in the dataframe and would like to update the DB to reflect the changes.

I tried:

`db.session.query(sqlTableName).update({sqlTableName.sql_col_name: pdDataframe.pd_col_name})`

But that just wiped out the column in the database (set every value to '0', the default). I tried a few other dataformats with no luck. I'm guessing that there is something funky going on with datatypes that I've mixed up, or you just aren't allowed to update a column with a variable like this directly.

I could do this with a loop but... that would be genuinely awful. Sorry for the basic question, after a long break from a project, my grasp of sqlalchemy has certainly waned.

Comment: Use `to_sql()` to upload the DataFrame to a temporary table and then run a UPDATE query on the main table with a JOIN to the temporary table on the common primary key value(s).

Comment: I thought about that but wanted to avoid the pointless sql use. Basically that writes the same column to the database twice.

Honestly surprised that you can't just use .update for a column like my original plan.

I might just write some code to create an SQL query that updates the column, and ignore the orm altogether. :/ Lame.

(Thanks for the reply btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading the DataFrame to a temporary table and then performing an UPDATE you don't need to write the SQL yourself, you can have SQLAlchemy Core do it for you:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa


def update_table_columns_from_df(engine, df, table_name, cols_to_update):
    metadata = sa.MetaData()
    main_table = sa.Table(table_name, metadata, autoload_with=engine)
    pk_columns = [x.name for x in main_table.primary_key.columns]

    df.to_sql("temp_table", engine, index=False, if_exists="replace")

    temp_table = sa.Table("temp_table", metadata, autoload_with=engine)
    with engine.begin() as conn:
        values_clause = {x: temp_table.columns[x] for x in cols_to_update}
        where_clause = sa.and_(
            main_table.columns[x] == temp_table.columns[x] for x in pk_columns
        )
        conn.execute(
            main_table.update().values(values_clause).where(where_clause)
        )
    temp_table.drop(engine)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_engine = sa.create_engine(
        "postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/test",
        echo=True,  # (for demonstration purposes)
    )
    with test_engine.begin() as test_conn:
        test_conn.exec_driver_sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS main_table")
        test_conn.exec_driver_sql(
            """\
            CREATE TABLE main_table ( 
            id1 integer NOT NULL,
            id2 integer NOT NULL,
            txt1 varchar(50),
            txt2 varchar(50),
            CONSTRAINT main_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2)
            )
            """
        )
        test_conn.exec_driver_sql(
            """\
            INSERT INTO main_table (id1, id2, txt1, txt2)
            VALUES (1, 1, 'foo', 'x'), (1, 2, 'bar', 'y'), (1, 3, 'baz', 'z')
            """
        )

    df_updates = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            (1, 1, "new_foo", "new_x"),
            (1, 3, "new_baz", "new_z"),
        ],
        columns=["id1", "id2", "txt1", "txt2"],
    )
    update_table_columns_from_df(
        test_engine, df_updates, "main_table", ["txt1", "txt2"]
    )
    """SQL emitted:
    UPDATE main_table 
    SET txt1=temp_table.txt1, txt2=temp_table.txt2 
    FROM temp_table 
    WHERE main_table.id1 = temp_table.id1 AND main_table.id2 = temp_table.id2
    """

    df_result = pd.read_sql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM main_table ORDER BY id1, id2", test_engine
    )
    print(df_result)
    """
       id1  id2     txt1   txt2
    0    1    1  new_foo  new_x
    1    1    2      bar      y
    2    1    3  new_baz  new_z
    """
```

Comment: I ended up trying bulk_update_mappings and annoyingly, this ended up using a 'question' for every row updated despite the single 'set' command in the generated SQL query. My sql server did not like this at all...... So it does seem like just pushing a table and then joining makes the most sense. I'm sure your solution will work perfectly, but in my situation, just leaving it as a separate table with a common index is acceptable, so I won't need the temp table. I CAN see this coming in handy in future though. Thanks so much for the help!